# How to install Oracle Apex Listener?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to install Oracle Apex 19.2 on windows using the official documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21611_01/doc.11/e21058/install.htm#AELIG7021

In the documentation they say, I have to download the Apex Listener from the URL : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/downloads/index.html

The listener file should be like : **apex_listener.version.number.zip**

When I click on the URL, I'm redirected to something else and I can't find Apex Listener to download.

Does anyone know where I can find Apex Listener please ?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what you need.

*Oracle REST Data Services* (ORDS) is what was previously called the *APEX Listener*.